# block access to site without asp.net URL redirection

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, redirect

I have three websites.  One main site and two sub sites in folders residing on one discountasp.Net server - www.sitea.com, www.siteb.com and www.sitec.com.

I redirect traffic to the sub sites (siteb and sitec) using URL Redirection in the web.config file thus:

```
<rule name="siteb" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.siteb.com$" />
            <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^/siteb/" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="\siteb\{R:0}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="sitec" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.sitec.com$" />
            <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^/sitec/" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="\sitec\{R:0}" />
        </rule>
```

My problem is I don't want the public to be able to type www.sitea.com/siteb/ and access the sub sites in this way.

How would I configure my server to stop this?

Thanks

Comment: URL rewriting and redirection are two different things, and you have to be clear about which you mean. Redirection sends the user's browser to a different address usually via an HTTP 302 code, whereas rewriting configures the server to treat a request for a URL as if it was for a different URL but without causing another request to be made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a second rule redirecting the people trying to access `www.sitea.com/siteb/` to `www.siteb.com`.

It would look like:

```
<rules>
    <rule name="Rewrite to siteb.com" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^siteb/" negate="true" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)?siteb\.com$" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/siteb/" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Prevent direct access">
        <match url="^siteb/" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)?sitea\.com" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="http://siteb.com" />
    </rule>
</rules>
```

I have changed a bit the `Rewrite` rule to make it shorter.
The `Redirect` sends a 301 (permanent) by default.
Everyone trying to access `www.sitea.com/siteb/` directly would be redirected to `www.siteb.com`, itself rewriting the first one (`www.sitea.com/siteb/`)

Comment: Hey Cheesemacfly.  You the man! That works perfectly, thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

when the page loads, you can get the page referer, like this:

```
Dim myReferer as string = Request.UrlReferrer
```

This will tell you where the page came from.  You could then split that string and do your comparison.

Another method, which may be better, is to pass a query String with the redirect.  Then, when your page loads, check for that query string.  If it doesn't exist, redirect the page or show an error.

Example redirect with Query String:

```
Response.Redirect("myPage.aspx?myId=SomeId")
```

Then check for the string in myPage:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
     myString as string =  Request.QueryString("myId")

end Sub
```

Comment: I think OP might actually be talking about rewriting.

Comment: Hi all, Actually I'm talking about redirecting.  Sorry that wasn't clearer in my original question. What I really want to do is redirect requests for www.sitea.com/siteb/ to www.siteb.com. Does that make sense?

Comment: Also I want to do it at the application level (in the web.config file)

Comment: So, does what I have posted work for you?  It is at the application level and does use redirect.

Comment: Hi Jason, Sorry, I don't think you've understood my question. I want to redirect requests at the application level, not individual pages. Maybe my terminology is not correct?

Comment: I think you can still use the code I provided but have it in the Global.Asax file (http://www.techrepublic.com/article/working-with-the-aspnet-globalasax-file/5771721).  This is a centralized file that all pages hit.  You can have common code here.  This page supports numerous events, including the Application_BeginRequest method, which I believe fires with every page request.